# Which one is better JSkype or Skype4Java

Tags: skype4java

Difference B/W JSkype Api and Skype4Java API?

Comment: Without telling us what you want to do, and how you define "better" (better in what way?? Ease of use? Set of features? Speed? Memory usage??), this question cannot really be answered.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSkype is an open source API which has not been looked at again by its developers for 5years now but it still works well.. though a problem with the new releases of skype can occur. On the other hand Skype API for Java is very easy to use but requires registration which is currently not being awarded.